# WordPress - How to extend 3rd party plugin class

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins, shortcode

I am trying to extend a 3rd party plugin class within my child theme.

I include my new class using the init hook, which works fine:

```
//add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function(){ //never fires
add_action( 'init', function(){ 

    require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/my-comment-form.php';

}, 5 );
```

I want to overwrite a function write_comments() in the original class.
This function fires when a shortcode declared in the original class executes.

In my class I have:

```
class my_frontend_comment_form extends orig_frontend_comment_form {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); <--- this executes fine

    }

    /*
       ** Original function in parent class that I want to overwrite:
    */
    function write_comments( $post_id, $results, $option, $id, $status = null ) {

        die('write_comments'); <!--- never executes
            //do new stuff here 
        }
    }
}    
$comment_form = new my_frontend_comment_form();
```

write_comments() in my class never fires. The original function always executes.

ATTEMPT 1 - remove and then re-add the shortcode: 
(do_comments() is the original shortcode function)

```
class my_frontend_comment_form extends orig_frontend_comment_form {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); <--- this executes fine
        remove_shortcode( 'orig-comment-form' );
        add_shortcode( 'orig-comment-form', 'do_comments' );
    }

    /*
       ** Original function in parent class that I want to overwrite:
    */
    function write_comments( $post_id, $results, $option, $id, $status = null ) {

        die('write_comments'); <!--- never executes
            //do new stuff here 
        }
    }
}    
$comment_form = new my_frontend_comment_form();
```

ATTEMPT 2 - include the shortcode function in my new class

```
class my_frontend_comment_form extends orig_frontend_comment_form {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); <--- this executes fine
        remove_shortcode( 'orig-comment-form' );
        add_shortcode( 'orig-comment-form', 'my_do_comments' );
    }

    /*
       ** Shortcode function
    */
    function my_do_comments( $atts ){
        die('my_do_comments'); <!--- never executes
        parent::do_comments( $atts );
    }

    /*
       ** Original function in parent class that I want to overwrite:
    */
    function write_comments( $post_id, $results, $option, $id, $status = null ) {

        die('write_comments'); <!--- never executes
            //do new stuff here 
        }
    }
}    
$comment_form = new my_frontend_comment_form();
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're defining a shortcode, filter or action inside a class. You can't just pass the function. The function should be `array($this, 'function_name')`. So try this (change for attempt 2).

```
class my_frontend_comment_form extends orig_frontend_comment_form {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); <--- this executes fine
    remove_shortcode( 'orig-comment-form' );
    add_shortcode( 'orig-comment-form', array($this, 'my_do_comments') );
  }

  /*
  ** Shortcode function
  */
  function my_do_comments( $atts ){
    die('my_do_comments'); <!--- never executes
    parent::do_comments( $atts );
  }

  /*
   ** Original function in parent class that I want to overwrite:
  */
  function write_comments( $post_id, $results, $option, $id, $status = null ) {

    die('write_comments'); <!--- never executes
        //do new stuff here 
    }
  }
}    
$comment_form = new my_frontend_comment_form();
```